# How do I make <button> fire CTRL+F and CTRL+G to a editable <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, textbox

How do I make  fire <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to a editable ?

I do not know how. I know I did the syntax is probably wrong. That is why I am asking of how to do it. There must be a way somehow to solve this by using Key Codes.

```
<div contentEditable="true" id="DivText" style="width:499px; height:230px;"></div>
<br>
<input type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('DivText').value= event.keyCode == 17 + event.keyCode == 102;" value="Search Text (CTRL+F)">  
<input type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('DivText').value= event.keyCode == 17 + event.keyCode == 103;" value="Search Selected Text (CTRL+G)">
```

The "Key Codes 17=CTRL and 102=f and 103=g" according to: http://expandinghead.net/keycode.html and http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/eventkeyboardmouse.shtml

Comment: @Mwizak thank you for editing. It looks nice and it is correct.